# Enum with customized values and Default value

Tags: java, string, enums

How to retrieve the enum name using value. By passing JOHN I need to retrieve the value as single

```
public enum Status {
    JOHN("single"),
    ALEX("married"),
    MARTHA("not known");
}
```

Is it possible to have default value as well in-case value does not match?

Comment: `Status.JOHN.getValue()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284472/how-to-cast-a-value-from-one-enum-to-another-in-java

Comment: cmt:- when value is not present in enum then return null instead of exception by converting the enum to a map

Comment: FYI, The enum constants are case sensitive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54150097/6700081

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you need to define a constructor and a `String` variable. Then you could create a getter method to return the `String` variable:

```
public enum Status {
    JOHN("single"),
    ALEX("married"),
    MARTHA("not known");
    private String value;
    private Status(String str) {
       value = str;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And then to get the value you can do:

```
Status.JOHN.getValue()
```

To get the enum from a `String` you can use the [`valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
Status.valueOf("JOHN").getValue();
```

However this will throw an error if the inputted `String` does not correspond to an enum. You could either wrap it in a try-catch to assign a default to it:

```
try {
   Status.valueOf("JOHN").getValue();
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
   //Assign default
}
```

However a better design might be to put the possibilities into a `HashMap` and see if the inputted `String` is in the `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, Status> status = new HashMap<>();
status.put("JOHN", Y.JOHN);
if(status.containsKey(input)) {
   //Do stuff
} else {
  //Assign default 
}
```

Comment: where do you pass JOHN to get the value as single?

Comment: Could you show a sample code of how to return a default value in-case input value does not match the enum

Answer (score 3):

Define your enum like

```
enum Status {
    JOHN("single"), ALEX("married"), MARTHA("not known");

    private String value;

    private Status(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Now to fetch the value :

```
System.out.println(Status.JOHN.getValue());
```

Here define a parameterized constructor for each enum and store this value in a member variable.

Comment: But how to pass the value. Status.JOHN is not possible when we have the value JOHN in a string variable right?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter You never said JOHN was a String. Use `Status.valueOf("JOHN").getValue()`

Comment: is it possible to send a default value if nothing matches?

Comment: If there is no match you will get the following exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant`. You can handle this exception using a `try-catch` and return "DEFAULT" from there.

Comment: isnt there a better way to handle it in enum class itself?

Comment: [This](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/java-enum-lookup-by-name-or-field-without-throwing-exceptions) will give you a good insight.

Answer (score 1):

A Java enum is an object, just like other objects in most ways. You can give it fields, methods, and constructors.

In this case, you can provide a `marriage` field and set it in a constructor just like you would for any other object.

Check out the official page on Java enums to see official examples, specifically the example with planets for your case. [The Java Tutorials: Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

---

Note also that you might not want to represent this specific data as an enum. You will be limited to only those 3 specific people by doing so. *This is only appropriate if you know that you definitely will have only this specific list of people for the entire lifetime of this code.* Otherwise you should just use a normal object.

A better idea might be to have a marriage enum and give your people a field of that type.

```
public enum MarriageStatus
{
    Married,
    NotMarried,
    Unknown;
}

public class Person
{
    String name = "Unknown";
    MarriageStatus marriageStatus = MarriageStatus.Unknown;
}
```